# Nginx/PHP/Javascript limiting video download ammount?

Tags: javascript, php, html, nginx

So i am sure many of you use youtube when youtube has a video playing if you pause it, It also stops downloading / transmitting the file to the user.

Example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iC685EyVto&t=0m33s While it is playing you see the grey download bar if you was to pause media it stops the download of the file. (Saving bandwidth)

I think it is a brilliant idea because if for what ever reason a file download is paused or waiting on a response from the user it stops using up the servers bandwidth.

I tested with limit_rate in nginx but it keeps downloading and does not stop regardless of if a user pauses or not.

Does anyone know how to achieve this or what the correct term for that feature is ? Throttling springs to my mind.

No buffering of videos while flash player is paused ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out it is called Dash Protocol and can be achieved with Nginx by using the RTMP module.